# Can't export MySQL database with PHPMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a MySQL 5.5 database in a web hosting, which I access using PHPMyAdmin (the hosting provider doesn't give me shell access). I back the database up using the "Export" function in PHPMyAdmin.

Recently, however, whenever I try to run the backup, I get an interrupted DB dump, and I see in it a PHPMyAdmin backtrace saying that "MySQL: the server has gone away". The two solutions to this, as I understand it, are:

- Changing the "max_allowed_packet" parameter in the server... but I can't do that.
- Repair tables... but I checked the status of the tables in the DB, including the ones where the dump usually stops, and they all seem OK.

I can always back it up in chunks, but it's a hassle to do that when the DB has about 40 tables. What can I do to fix this?